# pd.read_html for several pages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a few pages to crawl. On each page there is a table. That's what I exactly want to get. And the urls of the pages are only different by the last number. Is there anyway that I could use pd.read_html to get all the tables and merge the tables into one table?

```
import pandas as pd
url_head = 'http://www.kmzyw.com.cn/jiage/today_price.html?pageNum=1'
data =pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

Comment: You definitely can. How many pages are we talking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add each url output to a list in a loop, and then use `pd.concat` at the end to combine the list into one large dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = []
for i in range(1, N):
    url_head = 'http://www.kmzyw.com.cn/jiage/today_price.html?pageNum=%d' %i
    df_list.append(pd.read_html(url)[0])

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Replace `N` with the number of web pages you have plus one.

Answer (score 1):

@cs95 Thank you for your answer above. This is not an answer but I wanted to implement this for this url but it just pulls duplicate rows for the first page. Anything else I should add?
rawurl  https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/predefined/undervalued_growth_stocks?count=100&offset=0

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = []
for i in range(1, 3):
    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/predefined/undervalued_growth_stocks?count=100&offset=%d' %i
    df_list.append(pd.read_html(url)[0])

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```